# Deleting a minibuffer only frame on C-g

Tags: frames, minibuffer

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I'm trying to create a popup that runs an elisp funtion I've written which searches my library directory for pdfs, gets the user to choose an option (using completing read) and opens the selected pdf.

**What I've done**

Because I want it available as a keybinding in my desktop env, I'm running it through a wrapper using emacsclient. I'm calling:

```
emacsclient --eval "(mwe-pdf-lookup-and-quit)" -a ""
```

Which points to the function:

```
(defun mwe-pdf-lookup-and-quit ()
  (make-frame '((width . 80) (height . 25)
                (minibuffer . only)
                (name . "lookup")))
  (sleep-for 0.01)
  (select-frame-by-name "lookup")
  (select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))
  (message (completing-read ; This is where my pdf search function goes
            "Choose: "
            '("Option 1" "Option 2")))
  (delete-frame))
```

**The problem**

Works perfectly if I choose a file. The pdf is opened and the frame is deleted. The problem is, if I decide I don't want to open a file anymore and press C-g, the frame displays "Quit emacsclient request" and hangs around. I would like to know how I can delete the minibuffer frame instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `unwind-protect` like that:

```el
(make-frame '((width . 80) (height . 25)
                (minibuffer . only)
                (name . "lookup")))
  (sleep-for 0.01)
  (select-frame-by-name "lookup")
  (select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))
  (unwind-protect
      (message (completing-read ; This is where my pdf search function goes
        "Choose: "
        '("Option 1" "Option 2")))
    (delete-frame)))
```

The unwind forms are executed unconditionally, also in the case of <kbd>C-g</kbd>.

Comment: That works! Thank you